# Get MembershipProvider's Properties from Web.Config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I derived a class from `MembershipProvider` in `System.Web.Security` with the following definition:

```
   public class RedditMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
    {

        public RedditMembershipProvider()
        {

        }
        public override int PasswordAttemptWindow
        {
            get { return 10; }
        }
        /* snip all the similar properties definition
                 */
    }
```

The issue is I want when the `RedditMembershipProvider`  is instantiated, I want all the properties to be read from the web.config, not from the code definition above:

```
<membership defaultProvider="RedditMembershipProvider">
<providers>
<clear/>
<add name="RedditMembershipProvider" 
     type="RedditClone.Models.RedditMembershipProvider"
     PasswordAttemptWindow=20
   />
</providers>
</membership>
```

So when I call the `PasswordAttemptWindow` from the View, I should get 20, not 10. But now I am getting 10, not 20.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me! How can I make this kind of mistake?

I just need to read web.config in my code to get the value out

```
  public override int PasswordAttemptWindow
    {
        get { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["membership"].value; }
    }
```

An even easier way is to inherit the `RedditMembershipProvider` from `SqlMembershipProvider` and override only necessary details.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class YourMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{
    public override void Initialize(string name, NameValueCollection config)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(config["yourValue"]))
        {
            _yourValue = config["yourValue"];
        }

        base.Initialize(name, config);
    }

    string  _yourValue;
    public override string YourValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _yourValue;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Edit: typo.

Answer (score 0):

The answer 1 is elegant way. For example to read property `minRequiredPasswordLength` use

```
public override void Initialize(string name, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection config) {
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(config["minRequiredPasswordLength"])) {
        _minRequiredPasswordLength = Int32.Parse(config["minRequiredPasswordLength"]);
    } 
    base.Initialize(name, config);
}
```

and then

```
public override int MinRequiredPasswordLength {
    get { return _minRequiredPasswordLength; }
}
```